# reading primitives from file in C

Tags: c, file-io, stream, iostream

I am new to C, and want to read some data from a file.

Actually, I find many reading functions, fgetc, fgets, etc..
But I don't know which one/combination is the best to read a file with the following format:

```
0 1500 100.50
1 200     9
2 150     10
```

I just need to save each row above into a struct with three data members.

I just need to know the best practice to do that, hence I am new to C programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reading each line using [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).  With each line, you can then use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/).

```
FILE* f = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
if (f) { 
    char linebuff[1024];
    char* line = fgets(linebuff, 1024, f);
    while (line != NULL) {
        int first, second;
        float third;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %g", &first, &second, &third) == 3) {
            // do something with them.. 
        } else {
            // handle the case where it was not matched.
        }
        line = fgets(linebuff, 1024, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

This may have errors, but it's just meant to give you an example of how you might use the functions.  Be sure to validate what sscanf returns you.

Comment: So, why not using fscanf directly?

Comment: @Mohammed: because number formats in fscanf like %g skip whitespace including newlines. This will prevent you from checking that the file has three values per line.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `fscanf` also, but I like this advice better.

Comment: It works, but when I replaced float with double, it returned garbage data in the last column, do you know why?

Comment: You may need to supply the format %lf (lowercase L f) instead of %g.  What formatter did you use?

Comment: The above code also accepts a line like `1 2 3 abc\n`, which shows that just checking the number of fields is not enough.

Comment: it was meant to be an example and not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void
read_file(const char *fname)
{
    FILE *f;
    char line[1024];
    int lineno, int1, int2, nbytes;
    double dbl;


    if ((f = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (lineno = 1; fgets(line, sizeof line, f) != NULL; lineno++) {

        int fields = sscanf(line, " %d %d %lg %n", &int1, &int2, &dbl, &nbytes);
        if (fields != 3 || (size_t) nbytes != strlen(line)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "E: %s:%d: badly formatted data\n", fname, lineno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* do something with the numbers */
        fprintf(stdout, "number one is %d, number two is %d, number three is %f\n", int1, int2, dbl);
    }

    if (fclose(f) == EOF) {
        perror("fclose");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
        read_file("filename.txt");
        return 0;
}
```

Some notes on the code:

- The `fscanf` function is quite difficult to use. I had to experiment a while until I got it right. The space characters between the `%d` and `%lg` are necessary so that any white-space between the numbers is skipped. This is especially important at the end of the line, where the newline character must be read.
- Most of the code is concerned with checking errors thoroughly. Almost every return value of a function call is checked whether it succeeded or not. In addition, the number of fields and the number of characters that have been read are compared to the expected values.
- The format strings for `fscanf` and `fprintf` differ in subtle details. Be sure to read the documentation for them.
- I used the combination of `fgets` to read one line at a time and `sscanf` to parse the fields. I did this because it seemed impossible to me to match a single `\n` using `fscanf`.
- I used the GNU C Compiler with the standard warning flags `-Wall -Wextra`. This helped to avoid some easy mistakes.

**Update:** I forgot to check that each invocation of `fgets` reads exactly one line. There might be lines that are too long to fit into the buffer. One should check that the line always ends with `\n`.